# Connection Refused error on Fluent-bit Opentelemetry INPUT

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry, fluent-bit

I am trying to send logs from *Opentelemetry Collector Contrib* (export) to *Fluent-bit* using the Opentelemetry INPUT [plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/opentelemetry). But I get error in the OTel Contrib pod:

```
2023-06-30T14:17:07.770Z    warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:191  [core] [Channel #3 SubChannel #4] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {
  "Addr": "opentelemetry-fluent-bit.myNs.svc.cluster.local:4318",
  "ServerName": "opentelemetry-fluent-bit.myNS.svc.cluster.local:4318",
  "Attributes": null,
  "BalancerAttributes": null,
  "Type": 0,
  "Metadata": null
}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.96.150.150:4318: connect: connection refused"  {"grpc_log": true}
```

They both run as Pods on Kubernetes (in Doker Desktop).

Here is my fluent-bit yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: opentelemetry-fluent-bit
  namespace: myNS
  labels:
    app: opentelemetry-fluent-bit
spec:
  # replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: opentelemetry-fluent-bit
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: myNS
      labels:
        app: opentelemetry-fluent-bit
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fluent-bit
          image: fluent/fluent-bit
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 4318
            protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: fluent-bit-config-vol
              mountPath: /fluent-bit/etc/
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 1500Mi
              cpu: 500m
            requests:
              memory: 500Mi
              cpu: 500m
      serviceAccountName: otel-collector
      volumes:
        - name: fluent-bit-config-vol
          configMap:
            name: fluent-bit-config
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-config
  namespace: myNS
data:
  # Configuration files: server, input, filters and output
  # ======================================================
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf

    [INPUT]
        name              opentelemetry
        listen            127.0.0.1
        port              4318

    [OUTPUT]
        name              stdout
        match             *

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name               jsonparser
        Format             json

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: opentelemetry-fluent-bit
  namespace: myNS
  labels:
    app: opentelemetry-fluent-bit
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 4318
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: opentelemetry-fluent-bit
```

and here is the part of the yaml in the OTel Contrib:

```
...
exporters:
      
      otlp/fb:
        endpoint: http://opentelemetry-fluent-bit.myNS.svc.cluster.local:4318
        tls:
          insecure: true
...
```

any hint? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved. please see here https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/7632